# ASP Page Form Action not letting ASP Button onclick firing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

In my `asp` page I  have a `form` with action url which resonds on `asp button click` but now I have call the `onclick` method also of `ASP button` but `form action` not letting me to fire onclick event.
If i remove the `form action` from the asp page. I am able to fire the `onclick` of button. Actually I have to redirect to one page after action completes.My source code is:

```
<form action="URL1" runat="server" method="post">
<asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Submit"   runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click2"

</form>
```

C# code:

```
   protected void Button2_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test final");
        Response.Redirect("http://www.url2.com/");
    }
```

Comment: Is that your ONLY form?

Comment: no other data is also there but this is the main part.. some textbox data is also there

Comment: Do you have multiple FORM tags? Because that is not allowed in ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: Sorry sorry.. this is the ONLY FORM..

Comment: Why dont you use anchor tag here and redirect it directly if System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test final"); is not that important then?

Comment: @TheDictator yes that is not important .. but how do i use the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

Is your form tag well formed? It also needs to be a 'server control' by adding runat="server" and an id.

You currently have a typo: runnat="server" should be runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
    <form runat="server"> 
      .. 
     </form>
```

nothing more nothing less

Answer (score 0):

You can call java script function on your button client side click event like this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClientClick="javascript:return RedirectURL();" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click2" />
```

Create JavaScript function in head section

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function RedirectURL() {
            window.location = "Your URL goes here.";
 return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Tried this.. but not working only one thing is either this or form action

Answer (score 0):

take like this

```
<a href="http://www.url2.com/"> 
   <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="Server" Text="Button1">
 </asp:Label>
</a>
```

This might Help you.

Comment: not working... form action page is working only... instead of label i gave button

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of ASP.NET is that all content of a form element is POSTed back to the page class that originally created the html and served to the client. That's a necessary condition for an event handler to fire when you click the button.

But if you set the value of the action attribute on form element to the name of a different file, that overrides default behavior and all content is posted to that  new location. How can you then expect your event handler to fire if it's in a different location, and you are not posting any data to it.

If you set the action attribute of form element to the name of the file where your event click handler is defined then it'l surely fire. assuming that "Button2_Click2" is defined inside Default.aspx.

```
 <form action="Default.aspx" runat="server" method="post">
```

In this context you don't really need "action" attribute.

So the cause of your problem is not the presence of the action attribute but your redirecting of the postback to a different location.

Ultimately, this is a design problem - I have a feeling that you can accomplish your goal by redesigning your solution.